# Switch do not change a visibility of textView

Tags: java, android

My switch do not change a visibility of textView.

In properties of activity_first.xml i have set `visibility: none`

edit: all code:
edit: all code:

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private TextView tv3;
    private Switch switch1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
        tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3) ;
        switch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);



        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged (CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked){

            switch (buttonView.getId()) {
                case R.id.switch1:
                    if (isChecked == true) {
                        tv3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        tv3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i guess you want `tv3.setVisibility(View.GONE);` otherwise there will be some logical issue , post complete code

Comment: Did you get any error? Because there is no value such as `none` for any view. the values for visibility are `gone`, `visible` and `invisible`

Comment: On unrelated note: Your case block could be written as `tv3.setVisibility(isChecked ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);`

Comment: i dont got any error, what is wrong with logic here (visible - invisible) ? it's normal, one time we see this, one time we can't see

Comment: I am asking about this line in your question `visibility: none`

Comment: Make sure that the id if the switch is `switch1`

Comment: i have this set in "Properties" of layout, not in code

Comment: i'm sure, id is "switch1"

Comment: why don't you just go ahead and add complete code and in return get quick answer from any of these kind guys

Comment: now u have more :)

Comment: @philips You didn't define `tv3` View... Just find that element in layout.

Comment: i had this, but forgot to copy, anyway no working still

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) Move `onCheckedChanged` outside `onCreate`

2.) Link `onCheckedChanged` with `switch1` because currently they are not connected

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

    switch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    // link your listener with your switch1 
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged (CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked){

    switch (buttonView.getId()) {
        case R.id.switch1:
            if (isChecked == true) {
                tv3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                tv3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make it inside the onCreate too by doing this
        ``sw.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() { });``

Comment: the context of the OP question includes `implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {` , anonymous class can be another solution but is not required in this case